# Using a custom object to "hollow out" that same object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, extrude

*I'm a total Blender noob here, so I apologize in advance if I seem to have trouble understanding.*

I'm trying to create a "picnic basket". I created a simple trapezoid by extruding then resizing a plane. But the result is a solid box and I need to hollow it out.

I'm assuming there's a way to simply partially "insert" a copy of the trapezoid down into the top and use it to "hollow it out", but I'm not finding any info online.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Search for bool tool, it is an addon that does what you want very well.

Comment: You can also just select the top face, press i to inset and e to extrude down.

Comment: Delete the top face and assign a 'Solidify' modifier. Since your box is trapezoidal, an extrusion will produce an inside of a different shape from the outside, possibly even projecting through it.... but you could always scale the bottom inside face down...

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

WhatAMesh: I found a copy of "Bool Tool". Last version was 0.2 and is 4 years old. I installed it, but now where do I find it and how do I use it? (Like I said, I'm a noob.)

user2164882 & Robin: The top face is not a selectable material. My trapezoid is one solid object.

Comment: Follow up: Is the latest version of Blender (2.79b) incompatible with "BoolTool"? I installed & activated it, but no "BoolTool Tab" is added to my Tool Shelf (as described in another post.) :(

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a 'boolean modifier' which is already present in blender.

1. Select your trapezoid by right clicking on it.

   2. Create a copy of this trapezoid by pressing Shift+D.
   3. Move it upwards by pressing 'G' and 'Z'
   4. Scale it down a big by pressing 'S' and align is as shown below.

[image]

5. Now all you need to do is remove the top object from the bottom object. You can do this by adding a boolean modifier on the bottom big trapezoid.You can do this by selecting the bottom trapezoid and going to modifiers tab, click 'Add modifier' and selecting the boolean modifier as shown below.

[image]

6. Change the operation to 'difference' by clicking on the drop down menu.

[image]

7. Click the eye dropper tool and then click on the top smaller trapezoid.

[image]

8. Click on apply button.

[image]

9. Now you have your basket. You can now delete the top trapezoid by selecting and clicking delete.You will get something like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But it seems I screwed up somewhere. After I clicked Apply, all that is removed is the submerged portion of the smaller trapezoid. :(

Comment: Please save the file just before applying and share it here. I'll take a look.You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy + pasting the generated url here.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I still had the smaller trapezoid selected before I used the eyedropper. Selecting the bigger trapezoid first before selecting the object to extrude it with solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know! Please close this thread by marking this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There is another easier, cleaner way.

1. create a Cube
2. resize the cube on X or y axis so it becomes a rectangular prism
3. go int edit mode and select the top face
4. press i to inset the face.
5. press i+z to extrude the new face downward.
6. select the bottom face of the cube as well as the bottom face of the hole.
7. press s to resize it to a "picnic basket".

[image]